# Blocked list with lock in C

Tags: c, locking, block, mutex

While learning Mutex and Spinlock, I heard that there is a list containing blocked lock (or thread)? in C.

However, I don't know what is called or what it is. Please tell me what it is.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no such builtin in C, you must code it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in standard C, but you can create something like this pretty easily. Essentially you just do:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
struct mlist {
    int *l;
    int len;
};

void mlist_add(struct mlist *list, int obj) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    mlist->l[mlist->len] = obj;
    mlist->len += 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int mlist_get(int index) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int ret = mlist->l[index];
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Obviously this is not exactly complete code, but the actual implementation of this type is not too much work. You just need to keep data safety in mind. Which essentially means to lock threads out any time you are doing work on shared data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `mutex`, there are two versions for lock, **interruptible** and **UN-interruptible**.

`mutex_lock_interruptible()` puts the current process in **TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE**
state, So the current process sleeps until the state is changed to
`TASK_RUNNING`. For the process in `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`, there are two possible
events which may change the process state to `TASK_RUNNING`. First event is
obviously, when the `mutex` is available and another thing is, if any `signal` is
delivered to process.

But if the process is put into the **TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE** state, which is the
case when we invoke `mutex_lock()`,the only event which can wake up the process
is the `availability of resource`.

**Spin lock** is called `lock` with **busy-wait**. why `spin lock` needed ? Can we use the `semaphore/mutex` in `interrupt handlers`. The answer is yes and no. you can use the **up and unlock**, but can’t use **down and lock**, as these are `blocking calls` which put the `process to sleep` and we are not supposed to `sleep in interrupt handlers`. So, what if we want to achieve the `synchronization` in `interrupt handlers`? use `spinlock`.
for e.g

```
static spinlock_t slock;
static unsigned int pwait = 10000;

static ssize_t spin_write( struct file *filp, const char __user *buf,size_t sz, loff_t *fpos )
{
        printk("Write begins\n");
        spin_lock( &slock );
        printk("Write : Acquired a spinlock...\n");

        mdelay( pwait );
        /* Pretending to do some work */
        printk("Write done. Releasing the spinlock\n");

        spin_unlock( &slock );
        return sz;
}
```

Refer any good linux kernel book you will get all these.